# how do I use Ruby log4r colorize to print colored text at stdout and non-colored text to a file

Tags: ruby, logging, log4r

I use [log4r-color](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/log4r-color) as logger. It works great by putting colored text at stdout (console), till I tee the console output to a file. (`ruby myApp | tee console.log`). I have two questions:

1. How do I use log4r to print colored message at `STDOUT` and at the same time all `stdout` messages gets logged into a file. Can I give filename to ColorOutputter?
2. How do I colorize only the level label, not entire message?

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tee, you need two loggers, one for stdout, one for file.

I do not know `log4r-color`, i use `log4r`.

If you want to colorize `log4r` and you use PatternFormatter you can use %L for formatted log-level with this monkey-patch i wrote:

```
require 'log4r'

original_verbosity = $VERBOSE
$VERBOSE = nil
module Log4r
  class PatternFormatter
    DirectiveTable = {
      "c" => 'event.name',
      "C" => 'event.fullname',
      "d" => 'format_date',
      "g" => 'Log4r::GDC.get()',
      "t" => '(event.tracer.nil? ? "no trace" : event.tracer[0])',
      "T" => '(event.tracer.nil? ? "no trace" : event.tracer[0].split(File::SEPARATOR)[-1])',
      "m" => 'event.data',
      "h" => '(Thread.current[:name] or Thread.current.to_s)',
      "p" => 'Process.pid.to_s',
      "M" => 'format_object(event.data)',
      "l" => 'LNAMES[event.level]',
      "L" => %q|case LNAMES[event.level]
                when "ERROR"
                  "\e[31m#{LNAMES[event.level][0..3]}\e[0m"
                when "WARNING"
                  "\e[33m#{LNAMES[event.level][0..3]}\e[0m"
                when "INFO"
                  "\e[32m#{LNAMES[event.level][0..3]}\e[0m"
                else
                  LNAMES[event.level][0..3]
                end|,
      "x" => 'Log4r::NDC.get()',
      "X" => 'Log4r::MDC.get("DTR_REPLACE")',
      "%" => '"%"'
    }
    DirectiveRegexp = /([^%]*)((%-?\d*(\.\d+)?)([cCdgtTmhpMlLxX%]))?(\{.+?\})?(.*)/
  end
end
$VERBOSE = original_verbosity
```

this cuts level to be 4 characters wide also, you can remove `[0..3]`-s if you do not like it